# Azure Push Notification Registration not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-notificationhub

- I am trying to register an iOS device to Azure Notification Hubs
- Registration works - no error is thrown.
- calling `await _hub.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(0)` gets 0 records
- sending a test message returns `Message was successfully sent, but there were no matching targets.`

**Implementation:**

I have a `AzurePushNotificationsService` class, which i use to register the device.

```
public class AzurePushNotificationsService
{
    private readonly NotificationHubClient _hub;
    public AzurePushNotificationsService()
    {
        _hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("Endpoint=[endpoint]/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=[access_key]", "push_app_dev");
    }

    private async Task<string> RegisterDevice(string token)
    {
        string newRegistrationId = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
        {
            var registrations = await _hub.GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync(token, 100);
            foreach (var registration in registrations)
            {
                if (newRegistrationId == null)
                {
                    newRegistrationId = registration.RegistrationId;
                }
                else
                {
                    await _hub.DeleteRegistrationAsync(registration);
                }
            }
        }

        return newRegistrationId ?? await _hub.CreateRegistrationIdAsync();
    }

    public async Task<string> CreateOrUpdateRegistration(string token, DeviceType deviceType, string registrationId = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(registrationId))
            registrationId = await RegisterDevice(token);

        RegistrationDescription registration = null;
        switch (deviceType)
        {
            case DeviceType.Apple:
                registration = new AppleRegistrationDescription(token);
                break;
        }

        registration.RegistrationId = registrationId;

        var registrationStale = false;
        try
        {
            // throws no error.
            registration = await _hub.CreateOrUpdateRegistrationAsync(registration);
        }
        catch (MessagingException e)
        {
            var webEx = e.InnerException as WebException;
            if (webEx != null && webEx.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)webEx.Response;
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Gone)
                {
                    registrationStale = true;
                }
            }
        }

        // if the registration is stale and/or removed then it needs to be re-created with a new registrationId
        if (registrationStale)
            registrationId = await CreateOrUpdateRegistration(contactId, token, deviceType);

        return registrationId;
    }
}
```

I register a device:

```
string token = "9da952de6877b23738f5e744b6149750505417afc84d31290044643fa1493d2c".ToUpper();
var service = new AzurePushNotificationsService();
await service.CreateOrUpdateRegistration(token, DeviceType.Apple, null);
```

I send a Test message, and i get the message:

`Message was successfully sent, but there were no matching targets.`

Is it something that i am missing?